# composite two foreign key in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using SQLALchemy in flask. And I am confused how to define composite key with two foreign keys.
One foreign key from one table and second from another table.

```
class Store_category_mapping(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'store_category_mapping' 
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False) 
    store_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    store_name    = db.Column(db.String(50),  nullable=False)

    __table_args__ = (
        db.ForeignKeyConstraint(
            [category_id, store_id],
            [Category_master.category_id, Store_master.store_id]
        ),
        )
```

It gives this error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: ForeignKeyConstraint on
>   store_category_mapping(category_id, store_id) refers to multiple
>   remote tables: category_master and store_master

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a composite foreign key that references more than one remote table. Composite foreign keys are a way to ensure integrity when one remote table has a composite primary key.

If you want to make sure that you only ever have one `store_category_mapping` entry with a given combination of `category_id` and `store_id` you could go for a [UniqueConstraint](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#unique-constraint) instead.

I'm not familiar with flask, but I assume it would look somewhat like this:

```
class Store_category_mapping(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'store_category_mapping' 
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Category_master.category_id), nullable=False) 
    store_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Store_master.store_id), nullable=False)
    store_name    = db.Column(db.String(50),  nullable=False)

    __table_args__ = (
        db.UniqueConstraint('category_id','store_id'),
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ORM style, I got the exception `sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper Mapper[MyTable(mytable)] could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'mytable'` with shmee's answer, but it just needed PrimaryKeyConstraint instead of UniqueConstraint, or setting the mapped columns to be primary keys (or both)

```python
from sqlalchemy import UniqueConstraint, PrimaryKeyConstraint, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, DeclarativeBase, mapped_column

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class FornA(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'forn_a'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)


class FornB(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'forn_b'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)

# using PrimaryKeyContraint
class MyTableA(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mytable_a'
    __table_args__ = (
        PrimaryKeyConstraint('forn_a_id', 'forn_b_id'),
    )

    forn_a_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey(FornA.id))
    forn_b_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey(FornB.id))

# setting mapped columns to primary keys with UniqueConstraint
class MyTableB(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mytable_b'
    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint('forn_a_id', 'forn_b_id'),
    )

    forn_a_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        ForeignKey(FornA.id), primary_key=True
    )
    forn_b_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        ForeignKey(FornB.id), primary_key=True
    )
```